# Gradle and dependencies on Android Studio 3.0.1 error

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

[image: Error]

[image]
[image]

**Dependencies error**, I test other appCompat version but this error is here
I do anything, I test maven repo and re-install AS but this error is here!

Comment: hear is a lot's of changes tell me your `compileSdkVersion`

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.soheil.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: have you tried waht ther error message suggests?

Answer (score 0):

**Just do like the error says:**

Change the word `alpha1` to `beta1` and then Sync the project. Otherwise check the latest version and add it.